# How to print text between two round brackets ()

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I was trying to print text in between round brackets but I ended up with entire text.

Here is an what I have used.

```
import re

s = '₹ 24.00 (8%)'
result = re.search('((.*))', s)
print(result.group(2))
```

output:

```
₹ 24.00 (8%)
```

Expected output:

```
8%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
import re

s = '₹ 24.00 (8%)'
result = re.search('\((.*)\)', s)
print(result.group(1))
# 8%
```

You need to escape the brackets if they are literal.